# I Mounted ZFS to /home, but not linked?

Tags: mount, zfs

Both `/home` and `/tank/home` have a folder called `main` (which is my username).  However if I add another folder to `/home` it does not appear in `/tank/home`.  If I add another folder to `/tank/home` it does not appear in home.

When I type `sudo zfs mount` it says:

```
tank/home                        /home
tank                             /tank
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Well I thought they would be mirror images of each other (like /home would just be a pointer pointing to /tank/home)?  I do see that when I add data to /home that the /tank drive is filling up (so it is storing it correctly).

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior.

Even while they do match by default at creation time, you shouldn't confuse the dataset names, here `tank` and `tank/home` and the directories they are mounted to, initially `/tank` and `/tank/home`.

You (or someone else?) changed the `tank/home` mountpoint property to be `/home`. After doing that, the `tank` dataset can contain a directory named `home` and this directory is completely unrelated to the `/home` directory contained in the `tank/home` dataset.

Note also that `tank` is not a drive or even a volume, both `tank` and `tank/home` share the same storage pool so filling either of them will reduce their common available space.

Comment: Thanks - so there is a tank/home dataset AND a tank/home directory - this is very helpful to my understanding.